# How to skip the hasRole specified in the Spring Video

Tags: spring

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lpw4CkNTfiois) video about Spring Security - A Custom AccessDecisionVoter (LSS - Module 9 - Lesson 4)

i'm looking to authorize user for a specific action but we don't have hasRole concept in our application but certain values needs to be verified before authorization.

Can we comment hasRole('Admin') line in the above video and just use the Custom Decision Voter to have the custom code?

Comment: Any comments on this?

Comment: Anybody have any suggestions ???